# didBeginContact - bodyA & bodyB end Contact if one of them hits another category

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Here is the deal, I've got a basket, an Apple and an Orange bodies.
We are going to drop them into the basket.

I also want to know the presence of the Apple inside the basket, so I go ahead and add a didEndContact method.

Lets assume the apple is already inside the basket.
Now I drop the Orange in the basket, everything works fine until the Orange hits both the Apple and the surface which is the basket.

As soon as the Orange hits the Apple while it's seating in the basket, Apple category ends contact with basket category and therefore we get ballOneIntTheBasket = NO. bodyA becomes orange category and bodyB becomes basket category

How do I get apple category to stay connected with all the connected bodies?

didBeginContact code

```
if (bodyA == appleCategory && bodyB == basketCategory) {
appleInTheBasket= YES;
}

if (bodyA == orangeCategory && bodyB == basketCategory) {
orangeInTheBasket = true;
}
```

didEndContact code

```
if (bodyA == appleCategory && bodyB == basketCategory) {
appleInTheBasket = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the contact delegate for this, you can use the `allContactedBodies` property of `SKPhysicsBody`.

So, using

```
basket.physicsBody.allContactedBodies
```

will return you a `NSArray` of all `SKPhysicsBody` objects currently in contact with the basket.

You can use this property in the `-update:` method to monitor the basket.

Comment: would you know how to use the NSArray correctly I get error if I use the following [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756011/how-do-i-correctly-use-allcontactedbodies/23763167?noredirect=1#comment36584044_23763167) `NSArray *tempArray = [yourNode.physicsBody allContactedBodies];
for(SKNode *object in tempArray)
{
    if([object.name isEqualToString:@"theBall"])
        NSLog(@"found the ball");
} `